# Spring Boot Testing: JPA repository returning inconsistent data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

I am writing some integration tests in springboot, to test the business logic in service class.

### Steps in test:

```
1. Inserting some initial data in inmemory db using sql scripts.
2. Asserting that the inserted data is correct using read operation on repository.
3. Executing the service class logic which reads the initial data and does some modification on it and save it through repository
4. Asserting that the initial data got modified after service class execution on reading the data again.
```

Execute method in quoteProductDelegate does the required modification on this initial data and calls `save()` method on `pricePlanDetailsRepo`

**Expectation**: `line c` i.e., 2nd call to `findByProductIdAndVersion()` should return modified data

**Reality**: The data being returned is the same as initial data

**What I tried and observed so far:**

1. I tried debugging the service class, the data is infact getting
   modified and is being saved correctly in the database, still the code at `line c` returns initial data
2. If I remove `line a` and `line b`, then `line c` is able to return the expected modified data

Am i missing something here? How do I achieve the expectation here?

**Test Class:**

```
public class QuoteproductResourceWithOverrideRateCardTest extends BaseIntegrationTest
{
     @Inject
     private IQuoteProductDelegate quoteProductDelegate;
     
     @Inject
     private IPricePlanDetailsJpaRepository pricePlanDetailsRepo;
     
     @Test
     @Transactional
     @Sql(
     { "/insert_initial_data.sql" })
     @Sql(scripts = {"/cleanup_scripts"}, executionPhase = ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD)
     public void rateCardFlagEnabledAndRateCardPresentCatalogVersioningOverrideMecCatalogPrice() throws Exception
        {   
         
 a ----     PricePlan initialPricePlanData = pricePlanDetailsRepo.findByProductIdAndVersion("Product_59",1L);
 b ----     Assert.assertEquals(4000, initialPricePlanData.getAmount(), 0.1d);
            initialPricePlanData = null;
            Response response = quoteProductDelegate.execute(parameters);
 c ----     PricePlan modifiedPricePlan = pricePlanDetailsRepo.findByProductIdAndVersion("Product_59",1L);
            Assert.assertEquals(10000, modifiedPricePlan.getAmount(), 0.1d);
        }
}
```

**Repository:**

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "oracle.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
@Repository
public interface IPricePlanDetailsJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<PricePlan, String>
{
     @Query("SELECT p FROM PricePlan p WHERE p.rootId = ?1 and p.rootVersion = (SELECT MAX(q.rootVersion) FROM PricePlan q WHERE q.rootId = ?1 AND q.rootVersion <= ?2)")
     PricePlan findByProductIdAndVersion (@Param("productId") String productId, @Param("rootVersion") Long version);

}
```

Update: The initial data and the modified data are on same version

Comment: Several questions first: 1. What is the `BaseIntegrationTest` doing which you extend? Is the repository in some way manipulated there?
2. Why do you need the `cleanup_scripts`? If this is a standard spring boot JPA integration test you can just call `deleteAll()` on your repository in a `beforeEach` or `afterEach` to reset your repository.

Comment: your question is very good formated. But as you say the problem exists on quoteProductDelegate which actualy modifies and saves data. Do you think it is a good idea to let this class out of your posted code?

Comment: Your version logic is weird - if it's that important wouldn't any operation you do save a new version? And your test logic always gets the first one?

Comment: @Lorenz G. 1. BaseIntegrationTest is the class which is having springboottest configuration which every test class is extending. No repository calls are present there.2. Yeah we can use deleteAll() too

Comment: @Boug, Problem is not with service class, it is modifying and saving the data, which is getting saved ( checked thorugh H2 console as well). Problem is that if I read the data at starting of test then the second read is not working

Comment: @Deltaharis, modify operation is on the same version which was saved initially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was the issue here. Using `@Transactional` was somehow messing up with my tests. Once I removed transactional, it worked. There is a good article which you can read on why you should avoid using transactional in your spring tests.